# how can I check if the process starts when the button is pressed?

Tags: c#

I have a program which must install programs when the button "install" is pressed.
How can I verify if it works?

button click code:

```
void ButtonDiscord_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Installer disсord = InstallerDBRepository.GetInstaller("Discord");
            InstallingMethods.InstallInstaller(disсord);
            Process procDisсord = new Process();
            InstallingMethods.InstallProgram(procDisсord, disсord);
        }
```

the code of the methods used in it:

```
public static void InstallInstaller(Installer installer)
    {
        string path = $@"C:\Program Files\{installer.name}";
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        else
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "*");
        }
        installer.path = path;
        InstallerDBRepository.AddInstallerPath(installer, path);

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(installer.link), $@"{path}");
    }

 public static void InstallProgram(Process installingProcess, Installer installer)
    {
        installingProcess.StartInfo.FileName = installer.path;
        installingProcess.Start();
    }
```

Maybe I need to turn the program into an installer and check from there?

Comment: You could either add a logger or make a switch for a 'verbose' mode that outputs everything going on.